# On Demand Docker Container Run On AWS or Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, devops

I am interested in running builds/scripts on demand, inside a Docker container, on AWS or GCP.

I keep reading of the ECS service (https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) , but I am not sure it is what I need. I surely do not need a cluster of managed EC2 instances. I also don't think Google Container Engine is the answer.

I just need to start a Docker container, run a build or any script inside it and shut it down. The lifetime of the container would be max 1h. So it's not about long running, or scaling any application. Just start, run, stop a Docker container on demand. Which AWS or GCP service is most suitable for this requirement?

Besides the service, what HTTP endpoints of it do I need to call in order to automate this process?

My application receives some bash script from the user and has to fire up a container, run the script, shut everything down when it's finished or errored and come back with the script's output. I imagine it would connect to the created/runnig instance via SSH.

Any help or hint to the proper documentation is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This type of service currently does not exist on AWS. You still have to manage the underlying EC2 servers that the Docker containers run on. Hopefully in the near future something like this will be available.

Comment: @MarkB But I can still create, start and stop an EC2 instance (and run the Docker container inside it) programatically, right? This is what I thought of initially, but it seems a very blunt approach.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Unfortunately Docker isn't as streamlined on AWS currently as it could be. I too thought this was the way Docker should work on AWS and was surprised when I found out ECS still required you to manage a cluster of servers. All indications are that AWS is going to add a Kubernetes service very soon, and my hope is that it will work similar to how you have described in your question. I would watch the KubeCon conference this week, and the AWS Re:Invent conference later this month for announcements.